# Erro plugin Eclipse Android

Tags: android, android-eclipse

Estou tentando iniciar o Eclipse e fica sempre em 0% ao carregar os projetos.

A seguinte mensagem apare:

> the user operation is waiting for Android SDK Content Loader to
>   complete

Alguém já passou por essa situação?

Comment: O sdk do android esta corretamente setado no eclipse e com os paths corretos no seu S.O.??

Comment: Está setado corretamente, tanto é que eu vinha usando normalmente... não sei dizer ao certo o que causa esse problema. As respostas abaixo soluciona este problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver o problema é só correr o eclipse com a *flag* `-clean`

```
/Applications/eclipse/eclipse -clean
```

[Fonte SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15670474/1817673)

Comment: Vlw, é isso aí.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver dessa forma:

- Abrir o %seu_usuario%
- na pasta  .android
- deleta a pasta "cache"
- deleta o arquivo ddms.cfg which
- Iniciar o eclipse

Isto também funciona :D